# InvalidArgument=Value '18' is invalid to 'SelectedIndex' Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Tags: c#

I have a `Button` where I am able to save data into the database. To do that I will get the information on `Combobox` and on a `Textbox`. I got a collection of items iniside of the `Combobox` and cannot be changed at the moment.

Right now, I have 17 items and every time I save something it will pull to the next item using `cmbID.SelectedIndex += 1;`, but every time I pull to the last item from `Combobox` it will give me an error :

> InvalidArgument=Value '18' is invalid to 'SelectedIndex' Parameter name: SelectedIndex

To solve it I've tried to use an if statement:

```
if (cmbID.SelectedIndex >= 18)
{
    cmbID.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

But this is not working, basically if the `Combobox` reach '18' it should go back to the `SelectedIndex` choosen by me.

Do you guys have any idea I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have index more than (item count -1) for the combobox, so

```
if(cmbID.SelectedIndex == (cmbID.Items.Count - 1))
{
    cmbID.SelectedIndex =1;
}else
{
    cmbID.SelectedIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster is it OK now?